# C++ how do define friend function in another namespace

Tags: c++

I have a class declaration similar to this;

```
#include "other.h"
class A{
          public:
            A(){};
          private:
            friend Data someNamespace::function(A* elem);
        }
```

Now in another header file i have

```
//other.h
#include "A.h"
namespace someNamespace {
       Data function(A* elem);
    }
```

ANd .cpp file

```
//other.cpp
#include "other.h"
Data someNamespace::function(A* elem){
  // do something here
}
```

I cant figure out how to make the namespace function as a friend to the first class. function in namespace cannot acces private vairables of class A. What am i missing?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: member of class A is inaccessible

Comment: You have cyclic (unguarded) includes and `Data` is undefined.

Comment: Well, it is usually recommended to reduce the coupling between different objects, do you *really* need that function to be `friend`?

Comment: @Bob_ it definetly needs to be a friend. Only thing im not sure about is should i make a util class or just util methods. In my actual project these will handle data serialization. And different methods might serialize differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Forward declare `class A` so that you can declare `Data function(A* elem)` in your namespace so that you can name `someNamespace::function` within the class `A`.

```cpp
struct Data {};

class A;  // <-- *** You need this ***

namespace someNamespace {
    Data function(A* elem);
}

class A {
    friend Data someNamespace::function(A* elem);
};

Data someNamespace::function(A* elem) {
  return Data();
}
```

#### If this were multiple files

If the code appears in separate files, then one could imagine an **other.h** file looking like this:

```
#include "data.h"  // for the definition of `Data`

class A;  // so that `A*` makes sense

namespace someNamespace {
   Data function(A* elem);
}

#include "A.h"  // If the rest of the definition of `A` is needed.
                // "Include what you use" principle.

// remaining "other" declarations here
```

Comment: pointer to incomplete class typer is not allowed

Comment: @MarkoTaht Did you add some additional code that caused that error?

Comment: added class A forward declaration to other.h. In other.cpp i get now pointer to incomplete class not allowes. Also i removed #include "A.h" from other.h

Comment: @MarkoTaht You're not following my guidance then.  You need `class A;` to appear before `Data function(A* elem);`  If you remove the `#include "A.h"` then you'll need to replace it with `class A;` so that `Data function(A* elem);` is meaningful.

Comment: is it all in the same file or multiple files?

Comment: One file, many files, it's all the same to the compiler. Then the preprocessor sees a `#include` it effectively replaces it in the file being compiled with a copy of the included file.